How to filter JSON containing any of possible values, using jq
I have the following json fragment:
[
    "FOO": {
        "name": "Donald",
        "location": ["Stockholm","London"]
    },
    "BAR": {
        "name": "Walt",
        "location":  ["Stockholm","Munich"]
    },
    "BAZ": {
        "name": "Jack",
        "location":  ["Munich","Paris"]
    },
    "BUZ": {
        "name": "John",
        "location": ["London","Paris"]
    },
    "QUX": {
        "name": "Mickey"
    }
]

How would I use jq to filter to all the that have any of Munich or Paris--that is:
[
    "BAR": {
        "name": "Walt",
        "location":  ["Stockholm","Munich"]
    },
    "BAZ": {
        "name": "Jack",
        "location":  ["Munich","Paris"]
    },
    "BUZ": {
        "name": "John",
        "location": ["London","Paris"]
    }
]

(of course, also excluding those that have no location at all)
It seems like when I use or, I get duplicated output.

Use the IN function to test for items in a stream:
.[] |= select(IN(.location[]?; "Munich", "Paris"))

{
  "BAR": {
    "name": "Walt",
    "location": [
      "Stockholm",
      "Munich"
    ]
  },
  "BAZ": {
    "name": "Jack",
    "location": [
      "Munich",
      "Paris"
    ]
  },
  "BUZ": {
    "name": "John",
    "location": [
      "London",
      "Paris"
    ]
  }
}

Demo
Note that the outer symbols need to be object braces {}, not array brackets [].

Perfect; thanks!   Now what if the location has objects like "location": [ {"name":"London"}, {"name":"Paris"} ]--how to do the same IN operation for the name value rather than the whole object?

@PatrickSzalapski Instead of .location[]?, go deeper using .location[]?.name Demo
